# Android JSON Parsing and insertion into sqlite

Tags: android, json, listview, android-cursoradapter

Just for understanding.

Currently I have an asynctask that works like this:

```
String doInBackground(Void... params)
//Downloads a JSON and returns it to the onPostExecute().

void onPostExecute(String response)
//Parses the JSON which has an array of stuff and insert into sqlite.
 Call changeCursosr and notifyDataSetChanged.
```

Is this the right way to handle the insertion and refreshing of the listview? Currently I'm experiencing a slight hang whenever it hits the post execute. should I be parsing & inserting the data in the doInBackground instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` are not suited for any process-intensive things. They are generally reserved for doing things such as starting and stopping a `ProgressDialog`.

You should be making network calls as well as database calls inside `doInBackground` in addition to processing the data from those resources.

Comment: Should the fetching of data and changing of cursor be done in the onPostExecute?

Comment: No, fetching data should occur in `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 0):

From the AsyncTask [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

Since it is invoked in the UI thread, it is essentially a blocking process.  All the heavy lifting should be done in doOnBackground.

Comment: Should the fetching of data and changing of cursor be done in the onPostExecute?

Comment: If you are using a CursorAdapter, I would setup the query (to return the cursor) and notify the adapter in the postExecute.  I don't think the actual query wouldn't be executed till you return to the main thread to repaint the screen.  Also, i am not sure if it is required, but I always call "startManagingCursor(cursor)" on the new cursor so that resources will be managed by standard activity lifecycle.  If you are targeting Honeycomb or later (ICS), you may want to look at LoaderManager and CursorLoader also for Cursor Management.  Lastly, you could always try it and see  :)